# Will application crash if FileInputStream is not closed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have used FileInputStream to read .jks file in my web application. Unfortunately, i forgot to close the stream in the code and it is moved to production. FileInputStream is not a static stream, but a local variable.

I will get a good chance to fix this in one month or two month.

Meanwhile, will there be any chance my application will crash because of this mistake.? Do i need to move the fix very soon or it can wait two months.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Are you opening this stream just once at initialization, or are you opening it repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the file open for longer than necessary can have at least the following deleterious effects:

1. Resource leak, so you run out of file handles.
2. Locking the file against the next process that needs to use it.

Fix it now.

Comment: This is unquestionably a bug, but if he's just reading a keystore once on launch and not touching it again, it may not be worth dealing with an out-of-cycle deployment in a bureaucratic organization.

Comment: @chrylis And if he's running out of file handles, or keeping a customer master file locked all afternoon it will be. There isn't enough information here to decide.

Comment: He *did* say ".jks file".

Comment: Actually i am initializing Inputstream inside a method. So every time request comes to this method, new stream will be initialized.

I created a same program exactly similar and ran the same method 10000 times with 30 threads. All of them ran successfully without any error.  

Any comment on this test?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no. As long as the `FileInputStream` object is reclaimable by the Java Garbage Collector. `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` along with many other objects that wrap around system resource, such as file handles, use finalize methods to perform cleanup at Garbage Collection. It's not the best solution to rely on this behavior as the GC is not deterministic and file handles may be returned to the OS long after you have finished using it.

It will only really crash if file locking is used and you attempt to reopen the same file too quickly or you prevent the GC from collecting the stream objects.

Comment: @EJP Or that, but I don't think that will be a problem pertaining to running out of file handles. You will run out of memory long before running out of file handles. Unless OS policies restricts the number of file handles per process.